# Trying to create new user

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

Trying to update steam user to User schema if exist, otherwise create new steam user in mongodb. However I got the error below. How can I solve this, am I doing it wrongly?

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: imageURL: Path `imageURL` is required., username: Path
`username` is required., profileURL: Path `profileURL` is required.
```

```
const User = require('./models/user');

        User.findOne({ steamId: steamId}, function(err, user){
            if(user){
               return done(null, user);  
            }
            else{
                request(profileURL, function (error, response, body){
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(body);
                        var profile = data.response.players[0];

                        var user = new User();
                        user.username = profile.personame;
                        user.profileURL = profile.profileURL;
                        user.profileImageURL = profile.avatarmedium;
                        user.steamId = steamId;

                        user.save(function(err){
                            done(err, user);
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        done(err, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is this Sequelize as well? It looks like those fields are required, so you must populate them. If you can't, consider setting them as optional or adding in some placeholder value.

Comment: Solved it, because my model schema is set to required: true. Removed the required.

Comment: Great find! Worth adding a self-answer that goes into details and shows the change you made to the model.

Comment: However, im stuck ((again)) when the user is exist in the database, I try to update the user information in my db so it is the same in steam db. However I failed, do you know the way I could achieve this?

Comment: Worth posting a new question for that as that sounds like a new problem.

Comment: Alright, thank you :)

Comment: Here are the new problem on different threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440150/update-existing-user-data-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `require: true` inside my schema