# Update existing user data in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

Currently, I have managed to the save user information inside my database. However I wanted to update the user information inside my database when they logged in if there is changes of information inside Steam database. So it is the same inside my database.

Below are example of information inside my User schema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username:{
    type: String,
  },
  profileURL:{
    type: String,
  },
  profileImageURL:{
    type: String,
  },
  steamId:{
    type: String,
  }
});
```

Below are example of my app.js. When the user login, I checked if the user steamId exist inside my database, I want to update the user information such as username, profileURL, profileImageURL and its steamID if exist else I create a new user inside my database. How can I achieve this? Currently, I just return done(null, user).

```
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    apiKey: ''
    }, 
    function (identifier, done){
        var steamId = identifier.match(/\d+$/)[0];
        var profileURL = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' + 'api_Key' + '&steamids=' + steamId;

        User.findOne({ steamId: steamId}, function(err, user){
            if(user){
                return done(null, user); 
            }
            else{
                request(profileURL, function (error, response, body){
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) 
                    {
                        var data = JSON.parse(body);
                        var profile = data.response.players[0];
                        var user = new User();
                        user.username = profile.personaname;
                        user.profileURL = profile.profileurl;
                        user.profileImageURL = profile.avatarfull;
                        user.steamId = steamId;
                        user.save(function(err){
                            done(err, user);
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        done(err, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}));
```

Comment: Hello,
are you sure the example is complete? Where do you define the `User` variable?

Comment: Inside my app.js by using const User = require('./models/user');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an upsert-enabled update call. Try something like this:

```js
        request(profileURL, function(err, response, body){
          var data = JSON.parse(body);
          var user = {
          //... construct user object
          }
          
          User.findOneAndUpdate({ steamId: steamId }, user, {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}, function(err, newUser){
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            done(null, newUser);
          });
        });
```